# 2 dev computers, 1 C# solution using TFS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I work on a team using TFS to manage a C# project. I have 2 development computers, a high end desktop and a laptop.

Ok, the TFS server is located many states away.  The other developers are around the globe.  I work out of my house.  I really didn't think I needed to include this when I said "I am on a team"... Guess I was wrong.  I also have no ability to make any changes to the TFS Server and no one outside of my office will change anything anywhere to help me do this.

I work on both.  When I switch from one to the other, I have to remember to copy the files (which I often forget or don't have time to do).

I thought I could put the source files on OneDrive/DropBox and edit them there.  It worked fine for one computer, but the other said:

"The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control."

Any idea how I might fix this (doesn't anyone have ideas on this???) - or other ways I might solve this?

I just like the idea of working on my desktop, but being able to grab my laptop and run when I have to.

Links to existing answers are appreciated, but I couldn't figure out what to search on that addressed this (although I am sure it has been asked before.)

Thanks!

Comment: I saw *2 dev computers, 1 C# solution*, but I didn't find it all that disgusting.  Have you tried using shelvesets to move your not-yet-checked-in changes across computers?

Comment: You say you are using TFS, but do you _know how to use TFS_?

Comment: Where is that TFS running ?  I suppose it is running on your desktop, which then in fact acts as a server ?
Why don't you host it on tfs.visualstudio.com or on GitHub or Bitbucket (those last 2 are no TFS hosts but use Git which is a bit different)

Comment: do you use OneDrive, DropBox ot TFS?

Comment: use VSTS: https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question with the information I sort of thought was obvious.

Comment: try create a account in tfs.visualstudio.com and use that account to host your project in tfs server. you can check in and get latest easly.  i think you have to watch some videos and then you are ready. you dont have to setup or download anything. just create an account in tfs.visualstudio.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I have so far (not ideal, but works) is to use OneDrive (or DropBox - I just use OneDrive since it has more storage).  On the laptop, I downloaded the entire project.  All the TFS flags are set for the laptop, but the desktop can see them just as well.  I can code on the desktop, and as long as I hit "save all" before I leave, I can race out the door with my laptop and work remotely, with all the current code.

The drawbacks of this approach are: 
1) When I open the project on the desktop - it complains since all the TFS references are for the laptop. But only when I open it.
2) I have to use the laptop to get current and push changed files.  Not a big deal.
3) I can't really work on both the laptop and the desktop at the same time - but don't really care since I don't need to and that wasn't the goal anyway.

The benefits:
1) I don't have to remember to copy from one location to another, check for changed files, etc.
2) As long as I have my laptop, I can work. No need to check in code, shelve code, or play any other silly games in order to keep them in sync.
3) I can race out last minute and always know I have all the code in whatever state it was in.

In the long run, I would still like a slightly better solution.  I am guessing that I could tell OneDrive not to sync the TFS folders/files on each machine and then that would eliminate the message I get when I start on the desktop, but at this time, it's not worth the effort to figure out how to do this (although, if you know, feel free to comment.) But overall, I am now quite happy.

Fletcher

Since I always have my laptop when at the desktop, but the opposite is not true, this works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to use a share for your local workspace is going to be something that runs into little quirks all along the way.

I would recommend using the Shelve feature.  You would Shelve from one computer, then unshelve from the other.  It basically takes your chosen changes and moves them onto the server such that you then can unshelve them onto the other computer.  It is a way to save your changes to the server without checking them into the project.  You have your own shelvesets that don't effect the main branch.

Comment: Thank you, an answer that appears helpful. I will look into it!

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative** : Use Git

**TFS :** Map your project which is in TFS into any folder on your local. And **check it in** when you develop. And in other computer, press **Get Latest** button by clicking right click of your mouse to solution.

EDIT:

If you want to use TFS, go [TFS Express](http://tfs.visualstudio.com)  without download or setup.

Comment: You can't "just" use git, if the repo is set up for TFVC. The repo would need to be migrated.

Comment: Git is not an option and I am required to add check in comments with my code - not something I want/have time to do when just changing computers.

Comment: @David Makogon I think that he can cuts connection off with tfs his project and then connect his project to any git host.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to copy the files instead of just use TFS checked in and get latest version?
This will guaranty you have the latest version of code on both machine without problem.

Please also checked in your projects and solution files into TFS, and you don't miss anything.

If you think it will affect others, you can have your own branch to working on.

Comment: I have no access to make any changes to the TFS server, policies, or procedures.  I can't check in code that won't compile. And checking in code requires I add comments explaining what was done and why. It would be easier to just copy the files.  But that's a PITA or I don't have time when racing out the door.